# What happen to my email if i move to another hosting?

Tags: email, hosting

We decided to move to new hosting server(godaddy) from bluehost. and domain registered in networksolutions.
Question, what will happen to my old email, will my email still works and retrieve those email if we will move to new server?

Answer (score 0):

It will work for aslong as you keep paying for the webhosting, If you stop paying for Bluehost, then that/those emails made on that host will be deleted. I recommend making a new email with godaddy since you moved servers host.